# How does this command make a user a sudoer?

Tags: apt, sudo

According to [this DevStack guide](http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html), the following commands will give sudo privileges to the `stack` user:

```
apt-get install sudo -y || yum install -y sudo
echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

How does that work? What does each part of those commands do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `apt-get install sudo -y` - Used to install sudo package in Debian based
   systems and **y** is used to specify yes during installation.
2. `yum install -y sudo` - Used to install sudo package in fedora based systems and **y** is used to specify yes during installation.
3. `echo "stack ALL=(ALL_ NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers` -
   Concatenating the line `stack ALL=(ALL_ NOPASSWD: ALL` to the end of
   `/etc/sudoers` file.

Basically, you are installing the `sudo` package for a `Debian` or `fedora` based system and giving the user `stack` the right to run commands with `sudo` by appending that line to the `/etc/sudoers` file.